# Run the same shell script on multiple files at the same time

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script like this:

```
while read line
do
    a=`echo $line`

    while read line
    do
        <complex stuff>
    done < $a.txt
done < b.txt
```

Where `b.txt` has list of file names which is given as input to first while loop.

The second while loop should take the file having the same name in `b.txt` as input and perform some calculations on it.

The script is working fine but the problem here is the second while loop process has to performed on all the files mentioned in `b.txt` in parallel to save the time required to complete the full task.

But the above script will take file names one-by-one from `b.txt` and complete the task which is taking very long time.

Can this script be modified in such a way which executed the second while loop on all the files in `b.txt` in parallel at the same time?

Comment: `a=$(echo $line)` is pointless and will cause problems if lines are ever able to have spaces in them. Just use `< "$line.txt"`.

Comment: Note you have been asking some questions recently. It is good practise to provide some feedback and, eventually, accept an answer.

Comment: See www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: If you just need the inner loop to be run on multiple lines in parallel then move it to a script and run the script in the background. If you need more control over the parallel execution then you probably want `xargs` or `parallel`.

Comment: @Prashanth I agree with fedorqui . When you seek help not only is it polite and good practice to give feedback, but your reputation will increase as well for each accepted answer. When I read fedorqui's comment, I am not encouraged to spend time helping you.

Comment: @fedorqui........Thankyou for your suggestion. I will mae it a practise to accept an answer or provide my feedback if i still fnd any issues!!

Comment: @RamboRamon.......Parallel utility doesn't seem to exist in my system.

Comment: @rocky.......Thankyou for your suggestion.

Comment: @Prashanth - actions speak louder than words. When I check right now you still haven't accepted any answers or clarified in what way they were unstatisfying. When I look at the answers, they look valid to me. So if you are saying that none of these worked, I wonder about the likelihood of anyone being able to assist you.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to run each inner loop in the background (although it's impossible to say for certain without seeing the body.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    while read line
    do
        <complex stuff>
    done < "$line.txt" &
    #                  ^ A subshell is forked to run the loop, allowing
    #                    the outer loop to continue immediately.
done < b.txt
# Optional, but you may need to wait for all the background
# jobs to complete before proceeding
wait
```

Comment: @Prashanth you should see a check mark below the down arrow. Click on that.